# Who to find out if a WiFi-Device is compatible with WPA2-EAP?

Tags: linux, wifi, iw, wpa2-eap

Is there a way to find out with Tools like iw if a WiFi-Device will work with a 5GHZ WPA2-EAP WiFi?

Here is the output for my specific device (but the questions targets to find a general answer)

```
$ iw list
Wiphy phy1
max # scan SSIDs: 9
max scan IEs length: 2304 bytes
Retry short limit: 7
Retry long limit: 4
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
Band 1:
    Capabilities: 0x1963
        RX LDPC
        HT20/HT40
        Static SM Power Save
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        RX STBC 1-stream
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps
        * 5.5 Mbps
        * 11.0 Mbps
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (30.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
Band 2:
    Capabilities: 0x1863
        RX LDPC
        HT20/HT40
        Static SM Power Save
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        No RX STBC
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
        * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
        * 5190 MHz [38] (disabled)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
        * 5210 MHz [42] (disabled)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
        * 5230 MHz [46] (disabled)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (disabled)
        * 5280 MHz [56] (disabled)
        * 5300 MHz [60] (disabled)
        * 5320 MHz [64] (disabled)
        * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
        * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
        * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
        * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
        * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
        * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
        * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
        * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
        * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
        * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
        * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
        * 5745 MHz [149] (disabled)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (disabled)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (disabled)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (disabled)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (disabled)
        * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
        * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
        * 5960 MHz [192] (disabled)
        * 5980 MHz [196] (disabled)
        * 6000 MHz [200] (disabled)
        * 6020 MHz [204] (disabled)
        * 6040 MHz [208] (disabled)
        * 6060 MHz [212] (disabled)
        * 6080 MHz [216] (disabled)
Supported commands:
     * new_interface
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * start_ap
     * new_station
     * set_bss
     * join_ibss
     * set_pmksa
     * del_pmksa
     * flush_pmksa
     * remain_on_channel
     * frame
     * set_channel
     * connect
     * disconnect
Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0xd0
     * managed: 0x40 0xd0
     * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
WoWLAN support:
     * wake up on anything (device continues operating normally)
software interface modes (can always be added):
interface combinations are not supported
Device supports scan flush.
```

Answer (score 1):

WPA2 and EAP are typically not implemented by the device in hardware, but in software. On Linux, this [wpa_supplicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) is the program used for this, and it works with pretty much all WiFi devices.